How do I restore the Ubuntu Software icon?
I installed something, quite likely the KDE Desktop Environment, that caused the Ubuntu Software icon to become an exclamation point in a square. Is there a way I can get it back to what it was?
This is on Ubuntu 22.04.4
"Ubuntu Software" application is represented by the 3rd icon from the left below:


@guiverc My bad, I updated it to show Ubuntu 22.04.3.  But I am not clear on what you mean by release details.

@guiverc Oops, it turns out I have 22.04.4. I got the 22.04.03 from the value that came from uname -a, but that must just be the version at installation time. Settings->About->OS Name is: Ubuntu 22.04.04 LTS.

First, install GNOME Tweaks with
sudo apt install gnome-tweaks

Now open GNOME Tweaks, and open appearance -> icons. Choose Yaru.

On my version of gnome-tweaks: Appearance->Desktop Icons (section) shows 3 items: [Size, Position of New Icons , Show Personal Folder]

@Scooter Can you please edit your question and attach a screenshot?

I added the screenshot.

@Scooter No, I meant, a screenshot of GNOME Tweaks?

I don't know what application came up before as I believe I typed "gnome-tweaks" in the terminal. But in trying to take a screenshot now the "Appearance" section has just one line for Icons and I selected Yaru in the dropdown and it works now. Thanks!
